# Can admissible labelling contain Undec(Undecided) argument?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

My question is about argumentation theory, **admissible** sets or labelling.
We define: Label is admissible iff every **In** labeled argument is legally **In** and every **Out** labeled element us legally **Out**.
My question rises in this point: If labeled set contains **Undec** argument, is the labelling admissible or not? Is there always exist an admissible labelling of arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer for my own question:

The **empty set of arguments** is always admissible.

By definition, it is conflict-free, and since it contains no argument, it cannot be attacked, and therefore trivially defends itself. Therefore, it is admissible.